# Rename multiple files with variable extensions to remove beginning and end of filename

Tags: bash, grep, sed, awk, rename

I have multiple files I need to rename as below:

```
5891_1_0_AD3884_ACTCTCGA_S10.bam
5891_1_0_AD3884_ACTCTCGA_S10.bam.bai
5891_1_AD3875_GAGCTTGT_S1.bam
5891_1_AD3875_GAGCTTGT_S1.bam.bai
5891_2_AD3876_ACACGGTT_S2_R1.bam
5891_2_AD3876_ACACGGTT_S2_R2.bam.bai
```

I would like to remove everything except AD**** so that the resulting filenames would be:

```
AD3884.bam
AD3884.bam.bai
AD3875.bam
AD3875.bam.bai
AD3876.bam
AD3876.bam.bai
```

The number of underscores ("_") before and after the AD**** is not always consistent. Currently there are always 4 digits following the AD, but in the future it may increase to 5.

Ideally a bash solution from parameter expansion would be great (working in a Linux Ubuntu environment), though I have tried this without success. sed, awk, grep, or lastly rename solutions are also possible, though I have tried many versions of these without success. Any help would be much appreciated.

#### UPDATE

The rename solution from @steeldriver works perfectly.

I was able to make the solution from @Boba Fit work with the following modifications:

```
for file in *
do
 fn=AD"${file#*AD}"
 ext=${file#*.}
 mv $file rename/${fn%%_*}.${ext}
done
```

### New edit

One additional issue is that the AD may also be lowercase (ad). For example:

```
5891_1_0_ad3884_ACTCTCGA_S10.bam
5891_1_0_ad3884_ACTCTCGA_S10.bam.bai
5891_1_AD3875_GAGCTTGT_S1.bam
5891_1_AD3875_GAGCTTGT_S1.bam.bai
5891_2_AD3876_ACACGGTT_S2_R1.bam
5891_2_AD3876_ACACGGTT_S2_R2.bam.bai
```

For the final result its ok if they are all capitalized (AD):

```
AD3884.bam
AD3884.bam.bai
AD3875.bam
AD3875.bam.bai
AD3876.bam
AD3876.bam.bai
```

But I need to be able to recognize upper and lowercase (case-insensitive) in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a bash script for you

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
 name=$(echo "$file" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
 name=AD${name#*_AD}
 name=${name::6}
 extension=${file#*.}
 mv ${file} ${name}.${extension}
done
```

With `#` I remove all the (smallest possible) part in front of the string that matchs `*_AD`.
In the next line I cut the Sting in max length to 6.
I write the extension by remogin the smales part that matches `*.`.

Then we move the file to `${name}.${extension}`.

Hope it works well.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did have an error with this "script_rename.sh: 4: script_rename.sh: Bad substitution", but I was able to modify it to make it work. I will post above

Comment: That's because `${name::6}` is only for bash, not for sh or dash. So insert as first line `#!\bin\bash` so your system knows to run it as a bash and not as a shell script.

Comment: I have another layer of complexity, what if the AD is lowercase (ad)? Is it possible to make this case insensitive?

Comment: please give us a example (edit question)

Comment: I added an edit above

Comment: i add one line, please try again

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. Also works if there are trailing letters instead of numbers (as per my comment on the other rename solution). Fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With perl-based `rename`:

```
$ rename -n 's/.*(AD\d+).*?[.](.*)/$1.$2/' *.ba[im]
rename(5891_1_0_AD3884_ACTCTCGA_S10.bam, AD3884.bam)
rename(5891_1_0_AD3884_ACTCTCGA_S10.bam.bai, AD3884.bam.bai)
rename(5891_1_AD3875_GAGCTTGT_S1.bam, AD3875.bam)
rename(5891_1_AD3875_GAGCTTGT_S1.bam.bai, AD3875.bam.bai)
rename(5891_2_AD3876_ACACGGTT_S2_R1.bam, AD3876.bam)
rename(5891_2_AD3876_ACACGGTT_S2_R2.bam.bai, AD3876.bam.bai)
```

Remove the `-n` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I have another layer of complexity, what if the AD is lowercase (ad)? Is it possible to make this case insensitive?

Comment: @csijcs You can use the `/i` flag to make the whole match case-insensitive, so the command would become `rename -n 's/.*(AD\d+).*?[.](.*)/$1.$2/i' *.ba[im]`. Alternatively, if you only need `AD` to be case-insensitive, you may use the "or" regex operator (`|`) to also match `ad`. In this case the command would be `rename -n 's/.*(AD|ad\d+).*?[.](.*)/$1.$2/' *.ba[im]`.

Comment: Works great! One other thing I just noticed, as a test I put ADtest for the name rather than AD#### with numbers. I'm not likely to have be the case, but if I wanted it to not care whether there are letters or numbers after the AD (or ad), how would I do that?